BIN_TO_UUID y UUID_TO_BIN no existe en mySQL
Estoy usando XAMPP y Nodejs con mysql2 para realizar una conexión con una base de datos, sin embargo, tanto en mysql como en la consulta en nodejs, al momento de usar BIN_TO_UUID() o UUID_TO_BIN():


static async getAll({ genre }) {
        const result = await connection.query(
            "SELECT title, year, director, duration, poster, rate, BIN_TO_UUID(id) id FROM movie;"
        )

        console.log(result)
    }



En este caso me da el siguiente error:

code: 'ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST',
errno: 1305,
sql: 'SELECT title, year, director, duration, poster, rate, BIN_TO_UUID(id) id FROM movie;',
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: 'FUNCTION moviesdb.BIN_TO_UUID does not exist'

Y en mySQL, cuando intento esta linea de codigo:


CREATE TABLE movie (
    id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())),
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year INT NOT NULL,
    director VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    duration INT NOT NULL,
    poster TEXT,
    rate DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL
);



me sale este error:

#1901 - Function or expression 'UUID_TO_BIN()' cannot be used in the DEFAULT clause of id

¿Hay alguna alternativa que pueda usar en este caso o alguna forma de implementar UUID_TO_BIN Y BIN_TO_UUID?

Qué versión del motor estás usando? La pregunta tiene etiqueta mysql y mariadb, es conveniente aclarar cuál exactamente usas. Un saludo.

@jachguate dice que la versión que estoy usando es: "10.4.32-MariaDB" cuando utilizo "SELECT version()"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015720/255257
